# How to show a table with custom message in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is it possible to show a message before a table in MS SQL Server?

Assuming this have a table of NAMES with columns firstName and lastName

```
PRINT 'This is a list of names'
SELECT * FROM NAMES
```

This code/query shows only the tables firstName and lastName without the message 'This is a list of names'

Comment: Run the query from SSMS with the Results to Text option to see both the print and select output in the Results tab. With grid results, the print message is displayed in the Text tab and the result set in the separate Results tab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run the query from SSMS with the Results to Text option to see both the print and select output in the Results tab. With grid results, the print message is displayed in the Text tab and the result set in the separate Results tab. - Dan Guzman

This comment solved my problem, Sorry for not being able to elaborate more my problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can add computed columns (expressions) to your dataset like this:

```
SELECT 'This is a list of names' AS your_message, * FROM NAMES
```

if I understand your intention correctly.

Comment: This will also spit out this message with each row, making it a bit redundant.

Answer (score 0):

Without further details, here's an option:

```
create table #names (id int,first varchar(20), last varchar(20))
insert into #names values
('1', 'john', 'doe'),
('2', 'john', 'abc'),
('3', 'jason', 'williams')


select null,'THIS IS A LIST OF NAMES',null
union
select *
from #names
```

Edit: I just noticed you stated the table only has first and last, so you can ignore the id column, I just assumed there would be some kind of unique identifier in the table.